# Can I/Should I use FILL to fill a DATATABLE in VB.NET 2010

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datatable, vb.net-2010

I am a brand new, genuine noob, late starter, no previous coding experience at all AND yet also a (also brand new) trainee vb.net developer (internal move from different business area, not IT or anything, very much sink or swim in-at-the-deep-end).

First task is to 'modernise' a paper procedure, I have a simple front end that works ok. I am trying to process the DB entries that writes, later in a seperate console app, but I can't get the entries into a datatable (very simple DB, single table, dataset would be too complicated?).

I am not sure how to use modules, methods etc; my front end was a couple of simple forms so that kinda made it easier.

I've sourced the basic gist from Wrox Beginning VB2010 as employer is on VS2010. It says that fill works for dataset and datatable; I know that the table is created with the correct columns BUT it does not fill.

Here is my code:

```
Dim objDataAdapter As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim objConnection As SqlClient.SqlConnection

Dim strConn As String
Dim strTableName As String = "MyTableName"

Sub Main()

    strConn = "Server = MySQLServer\Name: Database = MyDatabase; Integrated Security = SSPI; Application Name =MyApplicationName"

    objDataAdapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection
    objConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConn)
    objConnection.Open()

    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT [MyFirstSQLColumn]"
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText &= ",[MySecondSQLColumn]"
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText &= "WHERE DATE IS TODAY(sic)"

    Dim dtbTodaysTableEntries As New DataTable(strTableName)
    dtbTodaysTableEntries.Columns.Add("FirstDTColumn")
    dtbTodaysTableEntries.Columns.Add("SecondDTColumn")

    objDataAdapter.Fill(dtbTodaysTableEntries)
    objConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Please, how to fix and what am I not understanding (gentle now) thanks.

Comment: There is no need to add cols to the DT, that will happen automatically.  How do you know it doesnt fill, you dont do anything with it after you do.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in then hover over the table reference, it gives an option to 'see' the datatable. it shows the column names I've specified but no data.

Comment: I also forgot to add (sorry long day) that it throws an exception. Can't remember exactly (as I'm at home now and cannot access work systems, over zealous DPA procedures) but it says there is a syntax error near the final ")"

Comment: I fail to see how you could get out of this code without an exception. Your sql is wrong at least in two points. No FROM and missing a space between column and WHERE

Comment: The data will be in the Rows collection.  The SQL is imperfect - among other things, DATE is a reserved work and what is "(sic)"? supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry that's my poor understanding of the SO editor I didn't think you'd all want/need to see the whole SQL query (which works in SSMS) and I am absolutely not allowed to post the 'real' query on the web. Apologies I should have been clearer on that.

Comment: You are using sqlclient libraries but indicated on your connection string that it is MySQL Server you are connecting to. They are 2 different things.

Comment: Sorry sorry it's not 'mysql', I'm referring to my msql server instance, how do I 'paraphrase' a server name?